# С# RichTextBox поле для ввода текста

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

Есть приложение WinForm, которое читает rtf файл и выводит его в richtextbox. Нужно в richtextbox вставить поля для ввода текста (аналог input type=text в html). 
Подскажите плиз как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам понадобились фичи html в RichTextBox, может просто использовать html вместо rtf? У меня впечатление, что rtf - это очень устаревший формат, который практически не поддерживается.

Comment: @Astronavigator старый != устаревший. Да он используется намного реже чем, например OOXML или ODF, но средства для чтения и создания RTF есть практически в любой ОС по умолчанию в отличие от других форматов с разметкой, и в ряде случаев этого формата более чем достаточно для простого форматирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `RichTextBox` в .Net WinForms - это оболочка над контролом из WinAPI. Ничего постороннего вы в него не запихнете, во всяком случае из .NET

Можно конечно насильственно для `Textbox` или `Button` указать `Control.Parent = myRichTextBox;`, однако вы не получите ожидаемого результата. Контрол конечно добавится внутрь `RichTextBox`, **НО** он добавится внутрь контейнера оборачивающего настоящий контрол и будет загораживать текст размещенный внутри и не будет следовать за скролом, в этом случае `RichTextBox` будет вести себя как обычный `Panel` на заднем плане которого в полный размер размещен `RichTextBox`, а на переднем все остальные контролы.

Не знаю как дела обстоят в WPF, там вроде нет привязки к WinAPI, а контрол для работы с RTF имеется, и даже называется также, но работать с ним несколько сложнее чем в WinForms, да и я очень сомневаюсь, что ваш вариант использования встречается так часто, чтобы в MS сочли необходимым реализацию такого функционала.

Если нужно использовать именно `RichTextBox`, то можно воспользоваться таким приемом - добавляем там где нужно что-то вводить пользователю в текст уникальную метку, которая с большой вероятностью не появится в тексте "случайно", что-то вроде `{N:type}`, вводим значения через обычные `TexBox`-ы и замещаем метки по окончании ввода от пользователя (N - номер метки, type - тип, например введенное число может быть представлено соответствующим числительным, это только возможный вариант).

В противном случае, стоит еще раз подумать над задачей и возможности решения какими-то другими способами и средствами.

Comment: Нашел компонент DevExpress richedit. Воспринимает как docx так и rtf. По описание вроде можно там размещать поля для ввода текста. Кто нибудь работал с этими компонентом? Пойдет он для моих целей?

Comment: @Yury у DevExpress вроде как собственная и техподдержка есть, это скорее к ним вопрос ну и в доках поковыряться

Comment: спасибо! буду ковырять доки